# ¿Cómo hacer para escuchar radio en sitio web seguro?

Tags: php, javascript, html, socket, stream

Buen día... ojala me puedan ayudar a solucionar este pequeño detalle.

El caso es que tengo un sitio web alojado en CloudFlare con el SSL activado, pero el script de la radio no me permite mostrar el sitio como seguro, pues el protocolo de la radio es http.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="{resources_url}/flash/radio.swf" style="width:280px;height:40px;margin-left: -7px;" ><param name="movie" value="{resources_url}/flash/player.swf">
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000'" ><param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=http://5.254.66.13:2164/;?group=0&amp;countrycode=MX&amp;similarprocess=0&amp;crashed=0/%3Bstream.nsv&amp;larila=ok&width=335&height=40&loop=0&autoplay=1&volume=70&showvolume=1&autostart=true&showstop=1&buttonwidth=40&sliderwidth=40&volumewidth=40&volumeheight=15&loadingcolor=ffffff&bgcolor=ffffff&bgcolor1=ffffff&bgcolor2=ffffff&slidercolor1=505050&slidercolor2=505050&buttoncolor=505050&buttonovercolor=505050" ></object>
```

Obviamente si lo cambio por ; no me funciona la radio.

Comment: intenta quitando el protocolo `value="mp3=//5.254.66.13:2164/;?......."`

Comment: ya lo he intentado también y nada :(

Comment: te manda algún error?

Comment: cuando pongo en chrome la url me transforma en etiqueta video el contenido: `<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="http://5.254.66.13:2164/;?group=0&amp;amp;countrycode=MX....." type="audio/mpeg"></video>`

Comment: solo que lo realiza sin flash, hay que ver la compatibilidad entre navegadores e ie8